# PHP : The procedure entry point php_checkuid could not be located

Tags: php, apache

I have an application hosted in a Windows machine that has two versions of PHP installed.

It's out of my control because there is another app of another vendor that somehow needs to use an older PHP version ; my app uses apache and the other vendor's app, IIS. The two PHP versions are installed in different folders, mine on 'c:\app\php' and the other vendor in 'c:\php'.

The problem is , when i go INSIDE the folder my PHP version is located (c:\app\php') and run PHP.EXE in command line, i get this error :

The procedure entry point php_checkuid could not be located in the dynamic link library C:\PHP\ext\somedll.dll

Why is this happening ? I'm calling PHP.EXE in the folder 'c:\app\php', not in 'c:\php'. How to fix that ?

Comment: Well, I have next to no idea about MS-Windows environments, but this sounds as if the library is loaded either directly by an absolute path configured in the php settings or that the library paths setting for your process point to the wrong folders. Most likely the two different different php versions require different libraries for various extensions. So you have to make sure you load the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

The solution for me was set the PHPRC environment variable to the folder of the correct PHP instance (c:\app\php). Before it was set to the wrong one (c:\php).

To do this search Windows for 'Edir environment variables for your account', look for 'PHPRC' and set it to the correct folder of the PHP instance.

Answer (score 0):

Put in the Windows Environmental Variable 'Path' the path of the php version you want to use.

Copy the complete content of phpForApache.ini to the php.ini file in that folder.

After that open a command window anywhere and type php -v should be working.

Good luck.